# Touch move is really slow

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I'm building a paint-like feature where the user can draw a line, but the touchmove event gets emitted really slow on my device (android phone), so the line becomes edgy. As soon as I connect the device to my PC and open the chrome devtools via USB debugging, everything works fine. On the phone emulator in desktop-chrome aren't any problems.

Here is a screenshot. The inner circle was drawn with the slow touch events, and for the outer one I connected the device to my PC.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is another screenshot showing the durations between individual "touchmove" event-calls. The top part (green values) occured when the devtools were open, the bottom part (red values) when they were closed.

[image: Screenshot]

The code:

```js
function DrawingCanvas(/* ... */) {
    // ...

    const handleTouchMove = (event) => {
        handleMouseMove(event.touches[0])
    }

    const handleMouseMove = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
        if (!isDrawing) {
            return
        }

        const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
        const x = clientX - canvasRect.x
        const y = clientY - canvasRect.y

        currentPath.current.addPoint([x, y])
        update()
    }

    const update = () => {
        clearCanvas()
        drawPath()
    }

    // ...

    useEffect(() => {
        const drawingCanvas = drawingCanvasRef.current

        // ...

        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", handleDrawStart)
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("touchend", handleDrawEnd)
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleDrawEnd)
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove)
        
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleDrawStart)
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleDrawEnd)
        drawingCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
        
        return () => {
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleDrawStart)
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove)
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("touchend", handleDrawEnd)
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("touchcancel", handleDrawEnd)

            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleDrawStart)
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleDrawEnd)
            drawingCanvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove)
        }
    })

    return <canvas /* ... */ />
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?
You can test it by yourself on the website: https://www.easymeme69.com/editor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow calling `event.preventDefault()` on the touchmove event fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same thing happen to me, down to not being able to reproduce with USB debugging open. Besides the `e.preventDefault()` hack, you can also set the touchable element's `touch-action: none;` in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing exactly the same situation, I'm developing a React app with some touch features implementing actions on `touchmove`.

All my tests are done inside Chrome on the Debian-based Raspberry OS distro.

It results in a deadly laggy UI with a real touch screen...except (this is when it becomes very interesting!) if the console is opened with Chrome mobile emulator, then even if I try to play with my finger on the real touch screen at this moment.

`touch-action: none` & `event.stopPropagation` hacks were already existing in my code and didn't change the game.

2 conclusions on that :

- The touch screen (and its driver) is fine
- The CPU is quite able to handle the load

As for now, the mystery is still opaque for me.

My feeling is that, somehow, Chrome is deliberately decreasing/increasing the touch events rate depending (correspondingly) on whether we're in a real use case or whether we're on the emulator. I created a simple fiddle to validate this hypothesis: https://jsfiddle.net/ncgtjesh/20/show

It seems to be the case since I can clearly that the emulator-enabled mode outputs 240 events/second while the real non-emulated interface is stuck to 120.

I'm quite surprised that the fixes enacted in the responses above made it since it seems to be a browser implementation choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I had no freezes on mobile or firefox, only on Chromium. Either disabling touchpad-overscroll-history-navigation in chrome-flags or `e.preventDefault()` can solve the problem.